# gcc makefile compilation & syntax. How c compiler is called and multiple included paths

Tags: c++, gcc, makefile, compilation, cygwin

I am pretty new in Linux/C++ so I need your help to understad the makefile below.

So my question are

1) how c compiler is called ? I can not find any calls and

2) what is the correct syntax to declared multiple included paths in the INC_DIR directive ?

This make file is used under cygwin64 terminal and Windows 10.

```
# the SOURCE definiton lets move your makefile to another position
CONFIG          = LIBRARY

# set pathes to the correct directories
SRC_DIR         = ../../../../source/Lib/TLibCommon
INC_DIR         = ../../../../source/Lib
LIB_DIR         = ../../../../lib
BIN_DIR         = ../../../../bin

SRC_DIR1        = ../../../../source/Lib/libmd5
SRC_DIR2        =
SRC_DIR3        =
SRC_DIR4        =


USER_INC_DIRS   = -I$(SRC_DIR)
USER_LIB_DIRS   =

ifeq ($(HIGHBITDEPTH), 1)
HBD=HighBitDepth
else
HBD=
endif

# intermediate directory for object files
OBJ_DIR         = ./objects$(HBD)

# the library name
PRJ_NAME        = TLibCommon$(HBD)

# version information
MAJOR_VER       = 0
MINOR_VER       = 1
VER             = $(MAJOR_VER).$(MINOR_VER)

# defines to set
DEFS            = -DMSYS_LINUX

# set objects
OBJS            = \
            $(OBJ_DIR)/Debug.o \
            $(OBJ_DIR)/TComPicYuv.o \
            $(OBJ_DIR)/TComYuv.o \
            $(OBJ_DIR)/ContextModel.o \
            $(OBJ_DIR)/ContextModel3DBuffer.o \
            $(OBJ_DIR)/SEI.o \
            $(OBJ_DIR)/TComCABACTables.o \
            $(OBJ_DIR)/TComSampleAdaptiveOffset.o \
            $(OBJ_DIR)/TComBitStream.o \
            $(OBJ_DIR)/TComChromaFormat.o \
            $(OBJ_DIR)/TComDataCU.o \
            $(OBJ_DIR)/TComLoopFilter.o \
            $(OBJ_DIR)/TComMotionInfo.o \
            $(OBJ_DIR)/TComPattern.o \
            $(OBJ_DIR)/TComPic.o \
            $(OBJ_DIR)/TComPicSym.o \
            $(OBJ_DIR)/TComPicYuvMD5.o \
            $(OBJ_DIR)/TComPrediction.o \
            $(OBJ_DIR)/TComRdCost.o \
            $(OBJ_DIR)/TComRom.o \
            $(OBJ_DIR)/TComSlice.o \
            $(OBJ_DIR)/TComTrQuant.o \
            $(OBJ_DIR)/TComTU.o \
            $(OBJ_DIR)/TComInterpolationFilter.o \
            $(OBJ_DIR)/libmd5.o \
            $(OBJ_DIR)/TComWeightPrediction.o \
            $(OBJ_DIR)/TComRdCostWeightPrediction.o \

LIBS                = -lpthread

DEBUG_LIBS          =
RELEASE_LIBS        =

STAT_LIBS           =
DYN_LIBS            = -ldl

# the libraries to link with
STAT_DEBUG_LIBS     =
STAT_RELEASE_LIBS   =
DYN_DEBUG_LIBS      =
DYN_RELEASE_LIBS    =

# name of the base makefile
MAKE_FILE_NAME      = ../../common/makefile.base

# include the base makefile
include $(MAKE_FILE_NAME)
```

Comment: gcc call is probably somewhere in the "base makefile" that is included at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The C compiler is likely in the `CC` variable set in some other makefile, presumably `../../common/makefile.base`, (otherwise the default, `cc`, will be used).

`INC_DIR` does not look like a place you would add additional C include search path entries.  This place looks more appropriate:

```
USER_INC_DIRS   = -I$(SRC_DIR)
```

Here, you would have to add additional directories with an `-I` prefix, like this:

```
USER_INC_DIRS   = -I$(SRC_DIR) -I/opt/enyo/include
```